# PHP : How to reduce Image size when displaying

Tags: php, image

I have MB size images from folder and when I populating it all it takes time to load my page, I want to reduce each image size from mb to kb while displaying NOT uploading. All I found is reducing the size while upload how about displaying is it possible?

```
foreach ($sql_getEachImage->results() as $res_child1) {
    $ext = pathinfo($res_child1->file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "gif"){
        $image_path = "ajax/news/".$res_child1->file_name;
        echo'<div>';
        howCanIreduceThisMbSizeImage($image_path, 70);
        echo'</div>';   
    }else{
        echo'<div style="">';
            echo $res_child1->file_name;
        echo'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image using the [`gd library`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

You could create a method that will save all images as jpeg since that has the lowest file size, you can't really do this on the fly as you'll need to send a header to the browser to tell it what type of file you're sending. You could create a method that saves a smaller version of an image and check for that image:

```
    <?php 

function reduceImageSize($source, $destination, $quality = 80) 
{
    // Create image based on mime type send the correct header
    switch (mime_content_type($source)) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
            break;

        case 'image/gif':
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($source);
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($source);
            break;

        default:
            // Image isn't jpeg, gif or png
            throw new Exception('Unknown file type');
            break;
    }

    // Always save as jpeg
    $path = pathinfo($destination, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
    $basename = pathinfo($destination, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

    // Save reduced file
    imagejpeg($im, $path . '/' . $basename . '.jpg', $quality);

    // Clean up
    imagedestroy($im);
}

// Loop through images and reduce size
foreach ($sql_getEachImage->results() as $res_child1) {
    try {
        $basename = pathinfo($res_child1->file_name, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        $filename = 'ajax/news/small/' . $basename . '.jpg';

        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            reduceImageSize('ajax/news/' . $res_child1->file_name, $filename, 70);
        }

        echo '<div>' . $filename . '</div>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<div style="">' . $res_child1->file_name . '</div>';
    }
}
```

This will attempt to resize the image only if it doesn't already exist in the reduced size and save it as a lower quality jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass 100 as the quality for imagejpeg(), try 50 and work downwards until the quality and size is acceptable.

```
imagejpeg($image, $savename, 50) ;
```